# How to append one text file to another text file

Tags: vb.net, file, append

I need to append 1 text file to another text file.

I've done several keyword searches, and keep coming up with instructions on adding text to an existing file ... which is not the same as appending one text file to another text file.

In a well-designed language, it might look something like the line below, with the contents of source2 added to source1.

Append(path/source1, path/source2, ResultCode)

Comment: [File.AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext) + [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext)

Comment: *...which is not the same as appending one text file to another text file*  but it is not all that different either

Comment: maybe so ... but everything I've looked at so far is way too verbose and overly complex ... even in DOS command line its as simple as "copy path/source1+path/source2 path/source1